# Trying to install rSync 3.x on debian 4 etch

Tags: linux, debian, rsync, apt, debian-etch

Whenver i use the official debian source link, and run the

```
apt-get install rsync
```

Debian automatically install me the rsync version 2.6.9.

I can confirm with the following command :

```
rsync --version
```

> it ouput : 
>   rsync version 2.6.9 protocol version 29

Now my question is the next : Is it possible to install rsync version 3.x on a debian 4 etch ? 
I have tried changing the source link to newer ones but that just brough more error with unverifiable packages and apt-get update that fails.

I mainly need this to make this script work : http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/migrating-a-linux-server-from-the-command-line-scripted

I need to use this to copy my machine to a new server, and it crashes on line 527, saying that the version variable is not yet set. From what i have seen in the script, it looks like its because it needs rsync version 3 or higher.

**EDIT :** 
The goal of this rsync is to transfer my current machine onto a newer one, with better hardware. Since the machine is mainly a mail and a dns server, i have to make sure there is nothing that is lost or not reinstalled. It is the reason why i opted in for a script that will ensure me that nothing is left.

Suggestion are welcomed.

Thanks for your help community !

Comment: I hope you're trying to get everything off this system and onto something a bit more modern. You're probably just going to have to tar it all up.

Comment: From what i can see on the rackspace script, i need to have the same exact system while i run the script on the new server... what are my possibilities here ?

Comment: First, you should [explain what your overall goal is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Updated the post. Thanks alot Micheal for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the repository at:

- http://archive.debian.net/etch/rsync

You will not be able to get a newer version of rsync through the debian package manager unless you upgrade the system to a new debian relase.
Your best bet is to download the source of rsync here:

- https://rsync.samba.org/download.html

And build it from source, making sure to install it in /usr/local so as not to interfere with the old one and avoiding your new copy being overwritten at a later date.

Now when you use rsync in a script just just use ***/usr/local/bin/rsync*** instead.